# Display button instead of text depending on state

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am displaying some data in a dynamic table, most of the data is text, but, there a couple buttons that I need to display.

So, I need to do something for that

here is the data I have so far

```
[ { "BET": 57630343, "CUSTOMER": 181645, "XX_FILL OPEN": true },
  { "BET": 57633044, "CUSTOMER": 181645, "XX_FILL OPEN": true },
  { "BET": 57633047, "CUSTOMER": 181645, "XX_FILL OPEN": true },
  { "BET": 57635034, "CUSTOMER": 181645, "XX_FILL OPEN": true } ]
```

which its been displayed like this:

[image]

everytime the data comes with an `XX...` at the beginning, should be a button, so look at this: `"XX_FILL OPEN": true` that is a button

here how I am rendering this table

in the controller I have something like this

```
  $scope.loadReports = function() {
    ReportsFactory.pendingBets(reportParam).then(function(data) {
      gridInfo = _.forEach(data, function(item) {return item;});
      $scope.rows = gridInfo;
      $scope.cols = Object.keys($scope.rows[0]);
    }
```

and the html

```
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="column in cols">{{column}}</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
            <td ng-repeat="column in cols">{{row[column]}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

so, what should I do to display a `button` instead of `true` everytime that the data comes with an `XX...` at the beginning ?

Comment: <td ng-repeat="column in cols">{{ column === true? row[column] : ''}} <button ng-if="column === true"></button></td>  Something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `ng-if` condition on the `indexOf` "XX" in `column`...

```
<td ng-repeat="column in cols" ng-init="isXX = column.indexOf('XX') === 0">
    <span ng-if="!isXX">{{row[column]}}</span>
    <button ng-if="isXX">{{row[column]}}</button>
</td>
```